# Unicode characters in PayPal IPN messages

Tags: unicode, paypal, paypal-ipn

Here is the link I am using to test: [https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donations&business=vincenkwen@gmail.com&currency_code=USD&notify_url=https://mysidte.org/testPaypal.php&item_name=问飞&item_number=0338&custom=打的费](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donations&business=vincenkwen@gmail.com&currency_code=USD&notify_url=https://mysidte.org/testPaypal.php&item_name=%E9%97%AE%E9%A3%9E&item_number=0338&custom=%E6%89%93%E7%9A%84%E8%B4%B9)

As you can see I set `item_name` and `custom` to be Chinese characters. However, in my IPN listener, all these characters are received back as `\u001a`s, though on the checkout page the item_name was correctly displayed.

Comment: I don't know IPN, but in general, you can't use unencoded non-ASCII characters in URLs, they have to be charset-encoded to bytes and then those bytes url-encoded. For example, those Chinese strings using UTF-8 for the charset would look like this in a URL: `...&item_name=%E9%97%AE%E9%A3%9E&...&custom=%E6%89%93%E7%9A%84%E8%B4%B9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **More Options** under [Language Encoding](https://www.paypal.com/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-language-encoding)